# How to detect if the delete key was pressed in Actionscript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, events, keyboard, flash-cs4

How do I determine if the delete key was pressed using actionscript?

```
addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, onKeyUp);

...

function onKeyUp(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    trace(event.keyCode);
}
```

The above code yields no value when delete, backspace, enter, and other command keys are pressed.  However, arrow keys *do* yield values.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
this.stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyPressed);
....

function onKeyPressed(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
   if (event.keyCode==Keyboard.DELETE) {
       .....
       }

}
```

it's workin nice...
But if you test movie from Flash, it will not work, so export to swf and test....

Comment: Interesting.  I guess because the simulator is running inside the FLash IDE, the IDE itself is intercepting delete commands.

Answer (score 2):

Just guessing you are using the TEXT_INPUT event, this doesn't work for delete and backspace. To catch those ones you can add an eventListener on the stage and listen to a `KeyboardEvent`.

Comment: No, I'm listening for events on the stage.  Code snippet updated to reflect this.

Comment: You must write stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, eventKeyDown) though (stage.* !) even though you are in the scope of the Document Class. Works for me...

Answer (score 1):

Code will work fine if the display object that you attached the listener is in focus. For global listening, as Theo said, you have to attach the listener to the `stage`. Accessing `stage` from an object that's not yet added to the display list will result in null error. Do it in the ADDED_TO_STAGE event handler to be safe.

Answer (score 1):

Old thread, but if anyone gets this far: in the Flash Player inside the IDE, these keys are associated with shortcuts. When you test your movie, choose Control>disable keyboard shortcuts in the player and you'll get the events back.