# AS3 | Event Listener for press Delete button

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I need an Event Listener for press Delete button from keyboard.

I try with this code:

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, deleteItem);
function deleteItem(e:KeyboardEvent) {
   if(e.charCode == 46){
       trace('1');
   }
}
```

but don't work. Please help me!

Comment: Take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1541276/how-to-detect-if-the-delete-key-was-pressed-in-actionscript-3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyboardEventUPHandler, false, 0, true);

function keyboardEventUPHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void 
{
    if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.DELETE)
    {
        //Keyboard.DELETE = 46
        //do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, deleteItem);
```

should be

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, deleteItem);
```